# How to explictly mention the constructor for std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector lists all the vector ctors.
But following two constructor cause compilation issues. Often in process of calling one, we end calling other.

```
vector( size_type count,
                 const T& value,
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init,
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

And it often boils down to changing {} to () or vice-versa to make things work.

Is there a way to make the choice of ctor clear? without worrying about the brackets.

P.S.- If you put proper brackets, following code works perfectly.

```
vector{elem1, elem2}; // Initializer list version
vector(vector_size, elem); // A vector of size `vector_size` all the items having value = elem
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you asking?

Comment: I don't understand when this problem arises. Could you give an example where the choice of which ctor to use is ambiguous?

Comment: std::vector<bool> v{4,false}; does not compile.

Comment: @GautamJha why would it compile? Why would you put `4` into `vector<bool>`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `{ ... }` with ... not empty will always prefer an `intializer_list<T>` constructor

Comment: @el.pescado - But he might want to create a vector of length 4 containing `false`.

Comment: You got things wrong `std::vector<int> v{4, 10}` is not equivalent to `std::vector<int> v(4, 10)`

Comment: The brackets partly choose which constructor is selected. If you don't want to worry about brackets you have to restrict yourself to the subset where the behavior is bracket independent. It makes more sense to me to worry about the bracket and choosing the correct one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During the process of selecting the constructors during list-initialization, any `initializer_list<E>` constructor is *strongly preferred* over any other constructor. That is, if it is at all possible to call it (even if it ends up being ill-formed due to narrowing, etc.), it will be chosen.

This leads to one weird quirk with `vector` that you just have to remember: if you have a `vector<I>` where `I` is some integral type, you run into the problem of passing two integral arguments to the constructor:

```
vec{a, b}; // calls std::initializer_list<I> ctor, because it can
vec(a, b); // std::initializer_list<I> ctor isn't viable because this isn't
           // list-initialization, so constructs a vector of size 'a' with
           // value 'b'
```

So take your example:

```
vec{4, false};
```

This will call the initializer-list constructor, even if what you wanted to do was create a vector of 4 bools that are all `false`. That constructor isn't viable, because of the narrowing conversion on `4`. That's why it won't compile. If you want to use the size/count constructor, you have to use parentheses (that is, don't do list-initialization):

```
vec(4, false);
```

This is only an issue for integral types because for non-integral types the initializer-list constructor simply wouldn't be viable:

```
std::vector<Foo> vec{4, Foo{}}; // creates a vector of 4 Foos
```

Comment: One has to use brackets to pick appropriate constructors. No work around?

Comment: @GautamJha What do you mean "no work around"? Just know what the syntax means and use the correct version, in this case  `()`s. That *is* the "workaround".

Comment: @GautamJha Brackets = `[]`. Braces = `{}`. Parenthesis = `()`. Can't see any *brackets*